# JQuery toggle() append html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple selection divs like cards. If one click on "select" then the title of that card is appended to the selection list.

My problem is the "unselect" button, which should instead remove the card title from the list. I've tried with `toggle()` `append()` and `remove()` without success. Card Title is appended but not removed.

```js
function accessories(){
  var accessories;
  $('.accessories').toggle(function() {

    accessories = $(this).closest('.card').find('.image-title').text();
    acc_txt = '<p> - ' + accessories + '</p>'; //element to append and remove later.
    $('#selection').append(acc_txt);
    $(this).css({background: '#35a8a5', border: '1px solid #35a8a5'});
    $(this).val('Unselect');

  }, function() {

    $('#selection').remove(acc_txt);
    $(this).css({background: '', border: ''});
    $(this).val('Select');

  });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  accessories();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4 card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://skiersedge.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cpw-vest.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <h3 class="image-title text-center">Core Power Weighted Vest™</h3>
  <div class="image-desc">
    <p><strong>Available for all models.</strong></p>
    <p>Increase the intensity of any workout with the addition of the Core Power weighted vest with soft flexible weights. This is the best fitting, most comfortable weighted vest available and is adjustable up to 22 lbs. in 1/2 lb. increments. Comes standard with 11 lbs.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" name="next" class="accessories" value="Select"/>
</div>

<div id="selection">here Should be appended the cards</div>
```

`.accessories` is the class of the button inside the card. So I search for the title `.image-title` and I append it. There are **multiple cards** on the page.
I don't know though how could I make the unselect button works.
How can I achieve it?

Comment: can you provide a stack snippet(it's one of the buttons on the editor) that shows the behavior you're encountering?

Comment: Please share your HTML structure aswell, or even better: make a JSFiddle

Comment: One solution could be using an iterator i.e [index] while appending and removing the elements. ```$('#selection')``` selector will return all whole markup. Hope this will help

Comment: Yes I'm going to provide a fiddle

Comment: Thanks @NishantMendiratta, I've inserted my html so you can see how would be the stracture. Could you provide an answer?

Comment: @Tschallacka Thanks! I've edited my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below snippet. Here I have replaced your toggle function with click function and using `.each` loop find out all the selected accessories on every click so only selected accessories will found. No need to remove un-selected accessories in this case.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.accessories').click(function() {     
    var current_status = $(this).val();
    if(current_status=='Select'){
      $(this).css({background: '#35a8a5', border: '1px solid #35a8a5'});
      $(this).val('Unselect');
    }else{
      $(this).css({background: '', border: ''});
      $(this).val('Select');
    }
    var accessories = "";
    $('.accessories[value="Unselect"]').each(function(){   
      var selection = $(this).closest('.card').find('.image-title').html();
      accessories += '<p> - ' + selection + '</p>';
    });
    $('#selection').html(accessories);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="selection">here Should be appended the cards</div><br/><br/>

<div class="col-sm-4 card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://skiersedge.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cpw-vest.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <h3 class="image-title text-center">Core Power Weighted Vest™</h3>
  <div class="image-desc">
    <p><strong>Available for all models.</strong></p>
    <p>Increase the intensity of any workout with the addition of the Core Power weighted vest with soft flexible weights. This is the best fitting, most comfortable weighted vest available and is adjustable up to 22 lbs. in 1/2 lb. increments. Comes standard with 11 lbs.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" name="next" class="accessories" value="Select"/>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://skiersedge.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cpw-vest.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <h3 class="image-title text-center">Core Power Weighted Vest™ - 1</h3>
  <div class="image-desc">
    <p><strong>Available for all models.</strong></p>
    <p>Increase the intensity of any workout with the addition of the Core Power weighted vest with soft flexible weights. This is the best fitting, most comfortable weighted vest available and is adjustable up to 22 lbs. in 1/2 lb. increments. Comes standard with 11 lbs.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" name="next" class="accessories" value="Select"/>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4 card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://skiersedge.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cpw-vest.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <h3 class="image-title text-center">Core Power Weighted Vest™ - 2</h3>
  <div class="image-desc">
    <p><strong>Available for all models.</strong></p>
    <p>Increase the intensity of any workout with the addition of the Core Power weighted vest with soft flexible weights. This is the best fitting, most comfortable weighted vest available and is adjustable up to 22 lbs. in 1/2 lb. increments. Comes standard with 11 lbs.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" name="next" class="accessories" value="Select"/>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-4 card">
  <div class="card-img">
    <img src="http://skiersedge.com.sg/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/cpw-vest.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <h3 class="image-title text-center">Core Power Weighted Vest™ - 3</h3>
  <div class="image-desc">
    <p><strong>Available for all models.</strong></p>
    <p>Increase the intensity of any workout with the addition of the Core Power weighted vest with soft flexible weights. This is the best fitting, most comfortable weighted vest available and is adjustable up to 22 lbs. in 1/2 lb. increments. Comes standard with 11 lbs.</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" name="next" class="accessories" value="Select"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there is some errors in your code. Furthermore it appends all the cards not the specific one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @XiLab if you will share your HTML then i will able to give precise answer. I have shared thought using which you will able to get solution.

Comment: Yes sorry, I've just paste my html. Have a look please. There are multiple cards on the same page like that! Thanks

Comment: You want to append name "Core Power Weighted Vest™". Right?

Comment: Yes, but for each element, I should click `select`= append and ùnselect`= remove

Comment: Awsome dude! Great stuff.